# Error when trying to install Firebase with pod relative to nanopb

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to install Firebase in my swift application with Cocoapod like this :

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

But got an error when i'm processing the pod install :

```
[!] Error installing nanopb
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/82/qk0yjdtx5xl0hnzsk2s2h30h0000gn/T/d20170722-19429-tm6t4q/file.tgz http://koti.kapsi.fi/~jpa/nanopb/download/nanopb-0.3.8.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   330  100   330    0     0   1941      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1952
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Unavailable
```

Just the server down ? or am I missing something
Is there an other way to do without nanopb ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally add

```
pod 'Firebase', '4.0.3'
```

this resolve the problem

Comment: where did you add this line?

Comment: I add it in the PodFile

Answer (score 6):

According to https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/4.0.4/FirebaseCore.podspec.json, nanopb is added in dependencies on FirebaseCore 4.0.4.

But nanopb server is not working now.(http://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/download/nanopb-0.3.8.tar.gz).

So you should specify Firebase/Core version to 4.0.3.

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.0.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

yes! so if you retry later, it should work.

Since it is a public repo, an address like https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Just add below line in your pod file.

```
pod 'Firebase', '4.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds like a me too, but I ran into this issue and it took half a day for the site to come back up to finish the install. If you run into this just point your browser at jap.kapsi.fi and if it shows an error 503 then try that again later. That worked for me as once I saw the site back up, I did pod install and it succeeded.